# How to identify an optimal subsample from a data set with missing values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to identify the largest possible contiguous subsample of a large data set. My data set consists of roughly 15,000 financial time series of up to 360 periods in length. I have imported the data into MATLAB as a 360 by 15,000 numerical matrix.

[image]

This matrix contains a lot of NaNs due to some of the financial data not being available for the entire period. In the illustration, NaN entries are shown in dark blue, and non-NaN entries appear in light blue. It is these light blue non-NaN entries which I would like to ideally combine into an optimal subsample.

I would like to find the largest possible contiguous block of data that is contained in my matrix, while ensuring that my matrix contains a sufficient number of periods.

In a first step I would like to sort my matrix from left to right in descending order by the number of non-NaN entries in each column, that is, I would like to sort by the vector obtained by entering `sum(~isnan(data),1)`.

In a second step I would like to find the sub-array of my data matrix that is at least 72 entries along the first dimension and is otherwise as large as possible, measured by the total number of entries.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: In an attempt to understand the question, stripping away all context. You have a matrix with values, including nan. You want to extract all columns with at least 72 non-nan values. Finally you want the columns sorted by their number of non-nan values. Did I miss something or understood it wrong?

Comment: That is correct; though it should be consecutive non-NaNs in each column.

Comment: I primarily work with panels of financial time series. May I ask you why do you need such a subsampled balanced panel?

Comment: I'm doing research into the eigenspectrum of variance-covariance matrices. For this, I first have to compute a historical variance-covariance matrix. I am not aware of any way to do this without a contiguous subsample-matrix; if you are, please kindly point me towards it. I am aware of the problem or survivorship bias, which becomes more severe as I require a longer minimum time series; but I am not sure how I should solve this.

Comment: For clarity, my post assumed I do need a contiguous subsample and I was asking how to obtain this. If alternatively, there is a way to compute a variance-covariance matrix for an unbalanced panel, this makes the question obsolete. If there is no way to do this however, my question of how to obtain such a subsample remains relevant.

Comment: You can compute a pairwise VCV matrix with `nancov()`, which might not be positive semidefinite, i.e. not invertible. This question mentions some approaches to fix this issue, but I am no expert: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/what-is-the-best-way-to-fix-a-covariance-matrix-that-is-not-positive-semi-defi

Comment: `nancov` is indeed the way to go to use all information for the covariance matrix. Afterwards, good luck in making a 15000*15000 matrix positive semidefinite and finding its eigenvalues... You're in for some trouble ^^ Unless you look at small sub-matrices...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### A big warning (may or may not apply depending on context)

As Oleg mentioned, when an observation is missing from a financial time series, it's often missing for reason: eg. the entity went bankrupt, the entity was delisted, or the instrument did not trade (i.e. illiquid). Constructing a sample without NaNs is likely equivalent to constructing a sample where none of these events occur!

For example, if this were hedge fund return data, selecting a sample without NaNs would exclude funds that blew up and ceased trading. Excluding imploded funds would bias estimates of expected returns upwards and estimates of variance or covariance downwards.

Picking a sample period with the fewest time series with NaNs would also exclude periods like the 2008 financial crisis, which may or may not make sense. Excluding 2008 could lead to an underestimate of how haywire things could get (though including it could lead to overestimate the probability of certain rare events).

Some things to do:

1. Pick a sample period as long as possible but be aware of the limitations.
2. Do your best to handle survivorship bias: eg. if NaNs represent delisting events, try to get some kind of delisting return.
3. You almost certainly will have an unbalanced panel with missing observations, and your algorithm will have to be deal with that.
4. Another general finance / panel data point, selecting a sample at some time point t and then following it into the future is perfectly ok. But selecting a sample based upon what happens during or after the sample period can be incredibly misleading.

#### Code that does what you asked:

This should do what you asked and be quite fast. Be aware of the problems though if whether an observation is missing is not random and orthogonal to what you care about.

Inputs are a T by n sized matrix X:

```
T = 360;              % number of time periods (i.e. rows) in X
n = 15000;            % number of time series (i.e. columns) in X
T_subsample = 72;     % desired length of sample (i.e. rows of newX)

% number of possible starting points for series of length T_subsample
nancount_periods = T - T_subsample + 1;   

nancount = zeros(n, nancount_periods, 'int32'); % will hold a count of NaNs

X_isnan = int32(isnan(X));

nancount(:,1) = sum(X_isnan(1:T_subsample, :))';  % 'initialize

% We need to obtain a count of nans in T_subsample sized window for each
% possible time period
j = 1;
for i=T_subsample + 1:T   
    % One pass: add new period in the window and subtract period no longer in the window 
    nancount(:,j+1) = nancount(:,j) + X_isnan(i,:)' - X_isnan(j,:)';
    j = j + 1;
end

indicator = nancount==0;  % indicator of whether starting_period, series
                          % has no NaNs 

% number of nonan series of length T_subsample by starting period
max_subsample_size_by_starting_period = sum(indicator); 
max_subsample_size = max(max_subsample_size_by_starting_period);

% find the best starting period
starting_period = find(max_subsample_size_by_starting_period==max_subsample_size, 1);
ending_period   = starting_period + T_subsample - 1;

columns_mask = indicator(:,starting_period);
columns      = find(columns_mask);   %holds the column ids we are using

newX = X(starting_period:ending_period, columns_mask);
```

Comment: +1. If I understood correctly, this gives you the **most** series that satisfy the minimal condition of 72 contiguous periods (no nans). Given that OP's condition cannot be satisfied without further clarification of "largest" subsample, this solution does the job. You can run it for different lengths, count the number of series, and pick the subsample that best satisfies your conditions. Finally, I would not recommend this approach in any financial research, since it introduces the so-called survivorship bias.

Comment: By this approach, I generally meant the subsampling of a panel of financial returns.

Comment: @Oleg Yeah, when an observation is missing from a financial time series, it's often missing for reason: eg. the entity went bankrupt, the entity was delisted, or the instrument did not trade (i.e. illiquid). Constructing a sample without NaNs is likely equivalent to constructing a sample where none of these events occur, thereby biasing returns etc... upward.

Comment: @Oleg Worth mentioning that nancov or other methods will a similar problem as long as the data is missing delisting returns (which is probably the big thing to be concerned about).

Comment: @dgoverde That is most likely 30 years of monthly data. I say that because I also work with the CRSP dataset and  the number of series you get over that period is approximately 15000 (you can quickly google the numebr of US companies now, it's much less than that), Also, the distribution of returns across time, looks exactly as it would a mothly dump from CRSP. The daily distribution of returns would be much sparser, with many NaNs in between. Most of those companies are small caps.

Comment: @oleg -  You're right.  My mistake.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @dgoverde You had a good observation for intraday returns, I just wanted to add a bit more context to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea,

Assuming you can rearrange the series, calculate the distance (you decide the metric, but if looking at is nan vs not is nan, Hamming is ok).

Now hierarchically cluster the series and rearrange them using either a dendrogram
or http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/examples/working-with-the-clustergram-function.html

---

You should probably prune any series that doesn't have a minimum number of non nan values before you start.

Comment: This does not ensure contiguity in the values of a single series. Nonetheless, might still be an interesting application.

Answer (score 2):

First I have only little insight in financial mathematics. I understood it that you want to find the longest continuous chain of non-NaN values for each time series. The time series should be sorted depending on the length of this chain and each time series, not containing a chain above a threshold, discarded. This can be done using

```
data = rand(360,15e3);
data(abs(data) <= 0.02) = NaN;

%% sort and chop data based on amount of consecutive non-NaN values
binary_data = ~isnan(data);

% find edges, denote their type and calculate the biggest chunk in each
% column
edges = [2*binary_data(1,:)-1; diff(binary_data, 1)];
chunk_size = diff(find(edges));
chunk_size(end+1) = numel(edges)-sum(chunk_size);
[row, ~, id] = find(edges);
num_row_elements = diff(find(row == 1));
num_row_elements(end+1) = numel(chunk_size) - sum(num_row_elements);
    %a chunk of NaN has a -1 in id, a chunk of non-NaN a 1
chunks_per_row = mat2cell(chunk_size .* id,num_row_elements,1);

% sort by largest consecutive block of non-NaNs
max_size = cellfun(@max, chunks_per_row);
[max_size_sorted, idx] = sort(max_size, 'descend');
data_sorted = data(:,idx);

% remove all elements that only have block sizes smaller then some number
some_number = 20;
data_sort_chop = data_sorted(:,max_size_sorted >= some_number);
```

Note that this can be done a lot simpler, if the order of periods within a time series doesn't matter, aka data([1 2 3],id) and data([3 1 2], id) are identical.

What I do not know is, if you want to discard all periods within a time series that don't correspond to the biggest value, get all those chains as individual time series, ...

Feel free to drop a comment if it has to be more specific.